# GDB process record: How extract instructions log from the saved execution log

Tags: gdb

I'm using the GDB record full mode in order to log some flow in my program. Now after I did it, I want to extract the instruction history from the executaion logs I saved using *record save /tmp/gdb_record_log* command.
I know that the gdb_record_log file is in elf format. But still I don't understand how to extract the instructions log from it. Can anyone pls help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the  GDB `record instruction-history` command not give you the info you are seeking?

Comment: it's not supported on *record full* target

Comment: Related (but not exactly duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31814199/50617